# How to Omit "DELETE" many properties from an Object?

Tags: typescript, object

I have two methods that return the following types `Pick<T, K>` and `Omit<T, K>` where Omit is `type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>`. I have some trouble when it comes to removing multiple properties from an object.

I have a method `pickOne` that selects one property from an object, a method `pickMany` that picks multiple properties from an object and a method omitOne that removes one property from an Object. I would like to have a OmitMany method to remove multiple properties from an Object, but I got stuck when fixing the type errors in the method.

Implementation of the methods:

```
export let pickOne = <T, K extends keyof T>(entity: T, props: K ): Pick<T, K> => {
    return { [props] : entity[props] } as Pick<T, K>
}

export let pickMany = <T, K extends keyof T>(entity: T, props: K[]) => {
   return props.reduce((s, prop) => (s[prop] = entity[prop], s) , {} as Pick<T, K>)
}

export let omitOne = <T, K extends keyof T>(entity: T, prop: K): Omit<T, K> => {
    const { [prop]: deleted, ...newState} = entity
    return newState
}

// And the OmitMany for so far I tried, the problem is with storing the entity
// in a temporary variable. This function only omits the last property in the
// the array. I would like an implementation simular to pickMany.
export let omitMany = <T, K extends keyof T>(entity: T, props: K[]): Omit<T, K> => {
    let result = entity as Omit<T, K>
    props.forEach(prop => {
        result = omitOne(entity, prop)
    })
    return result
}
```

I expect the output of `omitMany({x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, r: 4}, ['x', 'y'])` to be an object of type `{z: number, r: number}`, but right know the output is an object of type `{x: number, z: number, r: number}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has little to do with typescript. The types work out as you expect them to for `omitMany`, the only problem is that at run-time it does not remove all the properties you expect it to and this is cause by the fact that you call `omitOne` on `entity` instead of the previous result. This requires some type assertions unfortunately, but it will work:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

let omitOne = <T, K extends keyof T>(entity: T, prop: K): Omit<T, K> => {
    const { [prop]: deleted, ...newState } = entity
    return newState
}

let omitMany = <T, K extends keyof T>(entity: T, props: K[]): Omit<T, K> => {
    let result = entity as Omit<T, K>
    props.forEach(prop => {
        result = omitOne(result, prop as unknown as keyof Omit<T, K>) as Omit<T, K>
    })
    return result
}

let o = omitMany({ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, r: 4 }, ['x', 'y'])
console.log(o)
```

[Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AHgCoBooGkB8UC8UACggMYDWamAogB6kA2ArgCYTLkQgD2AZlBmw4cAKBEMIwKN0TAYAO2iEq2KBFrAI8lgGconHv1Q4AFFuBIQALgGYwAJ25gbWAJQ34SFbgJ4A3iJQQVCk3PI6Un5QANoOTgC6NmwSmiyYAHSZigDuAMrAAIaaUAC+BGryFqCBwfaSTPbyUDn5RRAiJWIp0rIAsgXyIOXeahpauvpcfAKm5pY2gnFgOi7R8e6wst54+P41Qd11OkwMUoRzoFAFep4ogrj7UEs66bzc9tQFpAAWJku+UACwWBUCOJzOPSQCggJjBpzsjjAVz0THk5Hk3GyTWuk0Mmy89xwrmR+LumAewJKrkedWADSacOAHS6kmk5RkSH6gxMUVoNgAjJhrFAAEyYABeNgAzJh7DYACylTDRADktBVmBVIBV6xEoXC3Ak6QY3AA5iZuK4gA)

Answer (score 2):

Since TS 3.5 and the standard `Omit` type:

```
function omit<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...props: K[]): Omit<T, K> {
    return props.reduce((o, k) => { delete o[k]; return o; }, { ...obj });
}
```