# Typescript: Get the type of the custom interface with 'this'?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

If I return a 'custom' type of an interface and I use typeof then I get the orginal type (I understand why, I read it), but I can get the custom type?

If I have the following:

```
interface X{
   A:()=>Omit<typeof this, "A">,
   B:()=>Omit<typeof this, "B">,
   C:()=>Omit<typeof this, "C">,
}

let X : X = {...}
```

If want to make the following possible:

I.e. 1:
X.A().B().C()

I.e. 2:
X.C().A().B()

But not:
X.A().B().A() (which currently is possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript does have a polymorphic `this` type, so you can write this interface:

```
interface X{
   A:()=>Omit<this, "A">,
   B:()=>Omit<this, "B">,
   C:()=>Omit<this, "C">,
}
```

However this will not do what you want, as the `this` type is bound when the interface is created not based on the type of the object the function was called on.

We can capture the type of the object the function is invoked on using the `this` parameter of a function and a generic type parameter. This will work as you expect it to:

```
interface X{
   A:<T>(this: T)=>Omit<T, "A">,
   B:<T>(this: T)=>Omit<T, "B">,
   C:<T>(this: T)=>Omit<T, "C">,
}

let X: X = null!

X.A().B().C()
X.C().A().B()
X.A().B().A() // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBoG8BQycEEBcAPACoB8AFGABbADO+yxAlALykDyAtsGCQDTIARLkGk+2HACEiZSjXqNWHbr2IDBk0eJzIAwjIrU6DZmy49+Q3VswBfTJgA2EMGgapkLZCACujxwCEDqgAdLjkTCGSESG6EZihcZHhkdFMCWExaZlMyAD0ecjQUEA)

Comment: I'm wondering why polymorphic `this` *doesn't* just evaluate to the type of the object on which the method is called.  Performance?  Or some correctness issue I'm not seeing?

Comment: @jcalz I think it would be a performance trap. Making every call site a generic inference site would probably kill performance. Then again, how often is polymorphic `this` used? Probably not a lot. Might be an interesting GH discussion topic although at this point it would just be an academic discussion as it would be a breaking change.

Comment: But what if I want to return a new type of X? I can only return this itself

Comment: You mean that you want to omit the properties from this? Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255212/how-to-omit-delete-many-properties-from-an-object